# Azure API call - az apim update - update customProperties

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I am using following az api call command `az apim show -n Namexxx -g RGxxx`. As an output I am getting below:

```
{
"additionalLocations": null,
"apiVersionConstraint": {
"minApiVersion": null
},
"certificates": null,
"createdAtUtc": "2021-10-15T08:49:38.486813+00:00",
"customProperties": {
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Protocols.Server.Http2": "false",
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Backend.Protocols.Ssl30": "false",
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Backend.Protocols.Tls10": "false",
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Backend.Protocols.Tls11": "false",
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Ciphers.TripleDes168": "true",
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Protocols.Ssl30": "false",
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Protocols.Tls10": "false",
"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Protocols.Tls11": "false"
},
```

I need to modify one of the `customProperties`. I tried to use command: `az apim update -n xxNamexx -g xxRGxx --set customProperties.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Ciphers.TripleDes168=false` but I am getting an error like below:

```
Couldn't find 'Microsoft' in 'customProperties.Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security'. Available options: ['Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Protocols.Server.Http2'
```

In MS API dos didn't find any useful information --> [AZ apim API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim/api?view=azure-cli-latest#az_apim_api_show)

Answer (score 1):

@tester81

Command group 'apim' is experimental and under development.I tested the functionality at my end and I was encountering the same issue in a WinPowershell.

I did find an different behavior at the Ubuntu Terminal.

If you are not making use of Win Powershell/cmd for invoking the az commandlet, you could probably try the below script at your end in your linux terminal.

```
customPropertiesUpdated=$(az apim show -n <APIM NAME> -g <APIM RESOURCE GROUP> --query customProperties | jq '."Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Security.Ciphers.TripleDes168" = "True"')
az apim update -n <APIM NAME> -g <APIM RESOURCE GROUP> --set customProperties="$customPropertiesUpdated"
```

The above script helped in changing the state. However, a relative script in    Win Powershell / Commad prompt / Cloud shell did not.

The Alternative or the **recommended** approach would be to make use of the REST API - until it is out of the experimental stage.

Please do see `properties.customProperties` - Api Management Service - [Create Or Update - REST API (Azure API Management) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/api-management-service/update?view=rest-apimanagement-2022-08-01&tabs=HTTP)

Comment: just wanted to check with you whether the above information helped ?

Comment: I don't really understand how it works. When I pass the custom properties as parameter in JSON I get `Attribute custom_properties in object ApiManagementServiceResource cannot be serialized.`. If I pass it as an object I get `Couldn't find '@{Microsoft' in '@{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ApiManagement.Gateway.Protocols'. Available options: ['additionalLocations', 'apiVersionConstraint', 'certificates',...`